# spark scala conditional join replace null values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes. I want to replace values in `col1` of `df1` where values are null using the values from `col1` of `df2`. Please keep in mind `df1` can have > 10^6 rows similarly to `df2` and that `df1` have some additional columns which are different from some addtional columns of `df2`.

I know how to do join but I do not know how to do some kind of conditional join here in Spark with Scala.

```
df1

name   | col1 | col2 | col3
----------------------------
foo    | 0.1  | ...
bar    | null |
hello  | 0.6  |
foobar | null |


df2 

name   | col1 | col7
--------------------
lorem  | 0.1  |
bar    | 0.52 |
foobar | 0.47 |
```

EDIT:

This is my current solution:

```
df1.select("name", "col2", "col3").join(df2, (df1("name") === df2("name")), "left").select(df1("name"), col("col1"))
```

EDIT2:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  ("foo", Seq(0.1), 10, "a"),
  ("bar", Seq(), 20, "b"),
  ("hello", Seq(0.1), 30, "c"),
  ("foobar", Seq(), 40, "d")
).toDF("name", "col1", "col2", "col3")

val df2 = Seq(
  ("lorem", Seq(0.1), "x"),
  ("bar", Seq(0.52), "y"),
  ("foobar", Seq(0.47), "z")
).toDF("name", "col1", "col7")

display(df1.
  join(df2, Seq("name"), "left_outer").
  select(df1("name"), coalesce(df1("col1"), df2("col1")).as("col1")))
```

returns:

```
name   | col1
bar    | []
foo    | [0.1]
foobar | []
hello  | [0.1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@coalesce(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) on `col1` after performing the `left join`.  To handle both `null`s and empty `array`s (in the case of ArrayType) as per revised requirement in the comments section, a `when/otherwise` clause is used, as shown below:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  ("foo",    Some(Seq(0.1)), 10, "a"),
  ("bar",    None,           20, "b"),
  ("hello",  Some(Seq(0.1)), 30, "c"),
  ("foobar", Some(Seq()),    40, "d")
).toDF("name", "col1", "col2", "col3")

val df2 = Seq(
  ("lorem",  Seq(0.1),  "x"),
  ("bar",    Seq(0.52), "y"),
  ("foobar", Seq(0.47), "z")
).toDF("name", "col1", "col7")

df1.
  join(df2, Seq("name"), "left_outer").
  select(
    df1("name"),
    coalesce(
      when(lit(df1.schema("col1").dataType.typeName) === "array" && size(df1("col1")) === 0, df2("col1")).otherwise(df1("col1")), 
      df2("col1")
    ).as("col1")
  ).
  show
/*
+------+------+
|  name|  col1|
+------+------+
|   foo| [0.1]|
|   bar|[0.52]|
| hello| [0.1]|
|foobar|[0.47]|
+------+------+
*/
```

---

UPDATE:

It appears that Spark, surprisingly, does not handle `conditionA && conditionB` the way most other languages do -- even when `conditionA` is false `conditionB` will still be evaluated, and replacing `&&` with nested `when/otherwise` still would not resolve the issue.  It might be due to limitations in how the internally translated `case/when/else` SQL is executed.

As a result, the above `when/otherwise` data-type check via array-specific function `size()` fails when `col1` is non-ArrayType.  Given that, I would forgo the dynamic column type check and perform different queries based on whether `col1` is ArrayType or not, assuming it's known upfront:

```
df1.
  join(df2, Seq("name"), "left_outer").
  select(
    df1("name"),
    coalesce(
      when(size(df1("col1")) === 0, df2("col1")).otherwise(df1("col1")),  // <-- if col1 is an array
      // df1("col1"),  // <-- if col1 is not an array
      df2("col1")
    ).as("col1")
  ).
  show
```

Comment: It does not work for me when I have col1 as ArrayType[String]

Comment: @darkman, I can't reproduce the said problem -- I've just modified `col1` to ArrayType in the sample data and the exact same `join/select` snippet works fine.

Comment: That's a requirement different from simply replacing `null` since `Seq()` is non-null.  Please see my revised answer with a slightly generalized sample dataset that takes care of both `null`s and empty `array`s (in the case of ArrayType).